# AUCTeX fontification for any command: overkill?

Tags: latex, auctex, font-lock, syntax-highlighting

Reading the AUCTeX manual I see that it is possible to add expressions to those one wants to highlight in a `.tex` file. There are also many specific suggestions around for how to add specific commands to the list `font-latex-keywords`. Now, coming from another editor (ST3) where it seems that the default is to highlight *anything* starting with `\`, I wonder whether there's any reason not to do this in Emacs and, if not, exactly how to do it.

(From what I understand, you can't use a regex to specify a list of keywords, is that right?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AUCTeX fontifies all control words: For known ones (added in `font-latex.el` or via AUCTeX style files), it uses different classes (e.g., `warning`, `function`, `textual` etc.) and for unknown ones, it simply uses the `font-latex-sedate-face` which defaults to `Foreground: DimGray`.  You can customize this face if you want a different appearance.  There is no fontification for control symbols.

You can load [this file](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/auctex.git/plain/tests/latex/fontification-general.tex) in your Emacs to see some basic ideas behind fontification of general macros in AUCTeX.

Comment: Thanks! I keep forgetting to disable `global-hl-line-mode`, which makes `describe-face` less helpful than it should be.